# How can I access resources of my application with another application (i.e Chrome)?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I want to view resources like html files, images, vectors of my application via Chrome. Some times when you open a txt, pdf document Chrome pops up and the url is like following:

```
content://com.package.name/path/path/file.txt
```

How can I access my applications resources like this? I think its something about FileProviders class or providers in manifest but I couldn't understand very much from the documentation. I am using Java.

Comment: "How can I access my applications resources like this?" -- if you literally mean "resources" (stuff in `res/`), then there is nothing built into Android to support this. You would have to create a custom `ContentProvider` that publishes those resources.

Comment: To be more specific I want to access "android_asset" folder. I can do it with WebView using `file:///android_asset/file.txt` scheme but I want to implement this to Google Chrome.

Comment: You would have to create a custom `ContentProvider` that publishes your assets.

Comment: Thanks. I am checking it out right now.